# How can I merge the lines of two files by having common headers?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to merge two files based on the common data present in them as header.

Following is the example

File1

```
>Feature scaffold1
1   100  g
101 200  g
201 300  g
>Feature scaffold2
1   100  g
01  500  g
>Feature scaffold3
10  500  g
>Feature scaffold4
10  300  g
```

File 2

```
>Feature scaffold1
500 500 r
900 1000    r
>Feature scaffold2
200 300 r
>Feature scaffold3
100 200 r
>Feature scaffold4
500 600 r
>Feature scaffold5
1   1000    r
```

And here's the kind of output I want:

```
>Feature scaffold1
1   100 g
101 200 g
201 300 g
500 500 r
900 1000    r
>Feature scaffold2
1   100 g
01  500 g
200 300 r
>Feature scaffold3
10  500 g
100 200 r
>Feature scaffold4
10  300 g
500 600 r
>Feature scaffold5
1   1000    r
```

I have tried some awk and sed but clearly have not been successful, how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^>/{ k=$1 FS $2 }
     NR==FNR{ 
         if (!/^>/) a[k]=(a[k]!="")? a[k] ORS $0: $0; next
     }
     k in a{ 
         print $0 ORS a[k]; delete a[k]; next 
     }1' file1 file2
```

- `/^>/{ k=$1 FS $2 }` - on encountering *header* line(i.e. `>Feature ...`) - compose a key `k` from the 1st `$1` and 2nd `$2` fields
- `NR==FNR{ ... }` - processing the 1st input file (`file1`):

  - `if (!/^>/) a[k]=(a[k]!="")? a[k] ORS $0: $0` - accumulate *non-header* lines into array `a` using current key `k`
  - `next` - jump to next record
- `k in a` - if current key based on `file2` record is in array `a`(based on `file1` records):

  - `print $0 ORS a[k]` - print related records
  - `delete a[k]` - delete processed item(s)

---

The output:

```
>Feature scaffold1
1   100  g
101 200  g
201 300  g
500 500 r
900 1000    r
>Feature scaffold2
1   100  g
01  500  g
200 300 r
>Feature scaffold3
10  500  g
100 200 r
>Feature scaffold4
10  300  g
500 600 r
>Feature scaffold5
1   1000    r
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach and to make it simpler.

```
grep -v '^scaffold' <(awk -v RS='>Feature ' \
    'NF{s[$1]=s[$1]$0} END{for (x in s)print RS""s[x]}' file[12])
```